# Cannot access a state property in Template Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to Vue. I am trying to learn Vue from online videos.In below snippet, inside Counter object, if I change template to render function the code starts working.

I am not getting why?

-----HTML----

```
<div id="app">
  <counter></counter>
  <counter></counter>
  <counter></counter>
  <button @click="inc">increment</button>
</div>
```

------Script tag------

```
const state = new Vue({
 data: {
    count: 0
 },
  methods: {
    inc() {
        this.count++;
    }
  }
});

const Counter = {
    template: `<div>{{state.count}}</div>`
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    Counter
  },
  methods: {
    inc() {
        state.inc();
    }
  }
})
```

If I change template inside Counter to this, it is working

```
render: h => h('div', state.count)
```

Comment: This looks like it would work better with Vuex instead of multiple Vue instances

Comment: Hi Phil,
This is something, I was just experimenting with.
According to my understanding, template will be converted to render function, so ideally this should have worked with template.

Answer (score 1):

`state` is a Vue instance, thus variables in the `data` property becomes accessible as properties in `state`, i.e: `state.count`, or `this.count` internally in the `state` instance.

Because `state.count` is valid, you could access it anywhere below the `state` instantiation.

Then `render: h => h('div', state.count)` becomes valid.

Now, any property accessed in `template` has to be internal properties of the Vue instance or component, or properties of `this` in `Count`.

Because the template in the `Counter` component will be converted to this corresponding render function:

```
render(h) {
    return h('div', this.state.count)
}
```

`{{state.count}}` is not referring to the `state.count` variable, but a property of the `Counter` component, `this.state.count`.

So for the sake of example (nothing you would do in real projects), here is how to make `state.count` valid in the `Counter` template:

```
const Counter = {
    template: `<div>{{state.count}}</div>`,
    data: () => ({
        state: {
            count: state.count
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: templates also would be converted to render function only ryt?

Comment: yes, they would. From that template, it would be converted to `render: h => h('div', this.state.count)`